# How do I get the content of string?

Tags: jquery, regex

If i have

```
<p>someword here</p>
<span>another thing here</span>new line
```

this is as a string
How do i get the content of span?

I want the result to be

```
another thing here
new line
```

**update :**

```
<script>
var string = "<span>this is span</span>new line";
var anchors = $('<div/>').append(string).find('span').text();
console.log(anchors);
</script>
```

**output:-**

```
this is span
```

and want to `new line`

Comment: You should post what you have already tried and ask for help fixing any errors.

Comment: @RuneFS check i am update my question with tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a id or class to span and using jquery

```
<span class="myclass" id="myid">another thing here</span>

jQuery('#myid').html();
```

or

```
jQuery('.myclass').html();
```

but the class method will give you all the elements having class "myclass"

Comment: since OP is looking for the text content you should use `.text()`

Comment: and if this is string then you can do like jQuery('<div/>').append(contentstring).find('span').text()